# Reciprocal sum of binomials and divisibility by $3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question, binomial-coefficients

We all know that $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k$ is not divisible by $3$.

> **QUESTION.** Is it true that the numerator of $a_n$ (in reduced form) is never divisible by $3$?
>   $$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{\binom{n}k}.$$

**POSTSCRIPT.** This the most detailed and pedagogical answer to any question that I asked here on MO. Thank you, Darij Grinberg.

Comment: Yes, it is true. Hint: The equality (7) of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151441/calculate-sums-of-inverses-of-binomial-coefficients/481686#481686 says that $a_n = \dfrac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \dfrac{2^k}{k}$. Now, let $3^s$ be the largest power of $3$ that is $\leq n+1$. Then, the addends of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \dfrac{2^k}{k}$ having the lowest $3$-adic valuation are $\dfrac{2^{3^s}}{3^s}$ and possibly $\dfrac{2^{2\cdot 3^{s}}}{2 \cdot 3^s}$ (the latter addend might not be in the sum). They both have $3$-adic valuation $-s$, which ...

Comment: ... is at least as large as the $3$-adic valuation of $n+1$. Thus, the only way how $a_n$ could be have positive $3$-adic valuation is if these two addends cancel each other $3$-adically (i.e., their sum has a $3$-adic valuation $> -s$). But this does not occur. To prove this, argue (by induction on $k$) that $2^{3^k} \equiv -1 \mod 3^{k+1}$ for all $k \geq 1$. This shows that the two addends are both $\equiv \dfrac{-1}{3^s} \mod 3$ (in the sense that their differences to $\dfrac{-1}{3^s}$ have positive $3$-adic valuation), and of course both $\dfrac{-1}{3^s}$ and its double ...

Comment: ... $\dfrac{-1}{3^s}$ have $3$-adic valuation $-s$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg What about updating it to an answer?

Comment: @Bullet51 and everyone up-voting this: I will, once I'm done grading my exam and moving out of this house (1+ week). At this moment it would just get people angry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the answer I hinted at in a comment, in real detail. Took me a while,
but I had no idea how tiresome such arguments are to expose...

Yes, it is true: see Corollary 6 **(b)** below. The proof relies on the
concept of a $p$-adic valuation of a rational number. It is defined as follows:

> **Definition.** Let $p$ be a prime. For each rational number $r$, we shall now
>   define an element $v_{p}\left(  r\right)  $ of the set $\mathbb{Z}\cup\left\{
> \infty\right\}  $ (where $\infty$ is understood to be a symbol that satisfies
>   the rules $\infty\geq n$ and $\infty+n=\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}
> \cup\left\{  \infty\right\}  $). We define it in three steps:
>
> - If $r=0$, then we set $v_{p}\left(  r\right)  =\infty$.
> - If $r\in\mathbb{Z}$, then we let $v_{p}\left(  r\right)  $ be the largest
>     $k\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $p^{k}\mid r$. (Here and in the following,
>     $\mathbb{N}$ means the set $\left\{  0,1,2,\ldots\right\}  $.)
> - If $r$ is any nonzero rational number, then we define $v_{p}\left(
>   r\right)  $ by $v_{p}\left(  r\right)  =v_{p}\left(  a\right)  -v_{p}\left(
>   b\right)  $, where $a$ and $b$ are two nonzero integers satisfying $r=a/b$.
>     (This is well-defined, since any nonzero rational number $r$ can be written as
>     $r=a/b$ for two nonzero integers $a$ and $b$, and since $v_{p}\left(
>   a\right)  -v_{p}\left(  b\right)  $ does not depend on the specific choice of
>     $a$ and $b$. Also, this new definition of $v_{p}\left(  r\right)  $ for
>     rational numbers $r$ does not conflict with the previous definition of
>     $v_{p}\left(  r\right)  $ for integers $r$. This is all easy to check.)
>
> Thus, an element $v_{p}\left(  r\right)  \in\mathbb{Z}\cup\left\{
> \infty\right\}  $ has been defined for each $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. This element
>   $v_{p}\left(  r\right)  $ will be called the *$p$-adic valuation of $r$*.

We will need the following rules for $p$-adic valuations:

> **Proposition 1.** Let $p$ be a prime.
>
> **(a)** We have $v_{p}\left(  ab\right)  =v_{p}\left(  a\right)  +v_{p}\left(
> b\right)  $ for any $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> **(b)** We have $v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  \geq\min\left\{  v_{p}\left(
> a\right)  ,v_{p}\left(  b\right)  \right\}  $ for any $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> **(c)** We have $v_{p}\left(  a^{k}\right)  =kv_{p}\left(  a\right)  $ for any
>   $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> **(d)** For any $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have the equivalence
>   $\left(  p^{i}\mid n\right)  \ \Longleftrightarrow\ \left(  v_{p}\left(
> n\right)  \geq i\right)  $.
>
> **(e)** If $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ satisfy $v_{p}\left(  a\right)  >v_{p}\left(
> b\right)  $, then $v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  =v_{p}\left(  b\right)  $.
>
> **(f)** Let $s$ and $t$ be two coprime integers such that $t\neq0$ and
>   $v_{p}\left(  \dfrac{s}{t}\right)  \leq0$. Then, $p\nmid s$.

*Proof of Proposition 1.* This is all well-known. Just in case, here are a few pointers:

Parts **(a)** and **(b)** of Proposition 1 are obvious in the case when one of
$a$ and $b$ is $0$ (because $v_{p}\left(  0\right)  =\infty\geq g$ for all
$g\in\mathbb{Z}\cup\left\{  \infty\right\}  $). Thus, they only need to be
proven in the case when both $a$ and $b$ are nonzero. But in this case, they
are exactly the parts **(c)** and **(d)** of Exercise 3.4.1 in [my *Introduction to Modern Algebra*
notes (version of 31 May 2019)](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/19s/notes.pdf) (the numbering might change in the future, but you can always find the version of 31 May 2019 frozen [on github](https://github.com/darijgr/algebra19s/releases/tag/2019-05-31)). (Be
warned that, in the latter notes, I use two different notations for what I am
here calling $v_{p}\left(  r\right)  $: The first notation is "$v_{p}\left(
r\right)  $", which I use only in the case when $r$ is an integer; the second
notation is "$w_{p}\left(  r\right)  $", which I use in the general case of
rational $r$. The reason why I do this is to avoid a conflict of notations,
even a theoretical one that doesn't actually happen; the notes are written for undergraduates.)

Proposition 1 **(c)** follows by induction on $k$. (The induction base uses
$v_{p}\left(  1\right)  =0$, while the induction step uses Proposition 1 **(a)**.)

Proposition 1 **(d)** is Lemma 2.13.25 in [my *Introduction to Modern Algebra*
notes (version of 31 May 2019)](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/19s/notes.pdf) (the numbering might change in the future, but you can always find the version of 31 May 2019 frozen [on github](https://github.com/darijgr/algebra19s/releases/tag/2019-05-31)). It is essentially a direct consequence of the
definition of $v_{p}\left(  n\right)  $.

**(e)** Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ satisfy $v_{p}\left(  a\right)  >v_{p}\left(
b\right)  $. We must prove that $v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  =v_{p}\left(
b\right)  $.

Assume the contrary. Thus, $v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  \neq v_{p}\left(
b\right)  $. But Proposition 1 **(b)** yields $v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)
\geq\min\left\{  v_{p}\left(  a\right)  ,v_{p}\left(  b\right)  \right\}
=v_{p}\left(  b\right)  $ (since $v_{p}\left(  a\right)  >v_{p}\left(
b\right)  $). Combined with $v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  \neq v_{p}\left(
b\right)  $, this yields $v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  >v_{p}\left(  b\right)  $.
On the other hand, $v_{p}\left(  \underbrace{-a}_{=a\left(  -1\right)
}\right)  =v_{p}\left(  a\left(  -1\right)  \right)  =v_{p}\left(  a\right)
+v_{p}\left(  -1\right)  $ (by Proposition 1 **(a)**, applied to $b=-1$).
Since $-1$ is an integer, we have $v_{p}\left(  -1\right)  \geq0$. (Actually,
$v_{p}\left(  -1\right)  =0$, but we don't need this.) Now, $v_{p}\left(
-a\right)  =v_{p}\left(  a\right)  +\underbrace{v_{p}\left(  -1\right)
}_{\geq0}\geq v_{p}\left(  a\right)  >v_{p}\left(  b\right)  $. Hence, both
$v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  $ and $v_{p}\left(  -a\right)  $ are $>v_{p}\left(
b\right)  $ (since we know that $v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  >v_{p}\left(
b\right)  $). Thus, $\min\left\{  v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  ,v_{p}\left(
-a\right)  \right\}  >v_{p}\left(  b\right)  $ (since $\min\left\{
v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  ,v_{p}\left(  -a\right)  \right\}  $ must be one of
the numbers $v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  $ and $v_{p}\left(  -a\right)  $).

But $b=\left(  a+b\right)  +\left(  -a\right)  $. Hence,
\begin{align*}
v_{p}\left(  b\right)  =v_{p}\left(  \left(  a+b\right)  +\left(  -a\right)
\right)  \geq\min\left\{  v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  ,v_{p}\left(  -a\right)
\right\}
\end{align*}
(by Proposition 1 **(b)**, applied to $a+b$ and $-a$ instead of $a$ and $b$).
This contradicts $\min\left\{  v_{p}\left(  a+b\right)  ,v_{p}\left(
-a\right)  \right\}  >v_{p}\left(  b\right)  $. This contradiction shows that
our assumption was wrong. Hence, Proposition 1 **(e)** is proven.

**(f)** Assume the contrary. Thus, $p\mid s$. Hence, $p^{1}=p\mid s$. But
Proposition 1 **(d)** (applied to $i=1$ and $n=s$) shows that we have the
equivalence $\left(  p^{1}\mid s\right)  \ \Longleftrightarrow\ \left(
v_{p}\left(  s\right)  \geq1\right)  $. Hence, we have $v_{p}\left(  s\right)
\geq1$ (since $p^{1}\mid s$).

But Proposition 1 **(a)** (applied to $a=\dfrac{s}{t}$ and $b=t$) yields
$v_{p}\left(  \dfrac{s}{t}\cdot t\right)  =\underbrace{v_{p}\left(  \dfrac
{s}{t}\right)  }_{\leq0}+v_{p}\left(  t\right)  \leq v_{p}\left(  t\right)  $.
Hence, $v_{p}\left(  t\right)  \geq v_{p}\left(  \underbrace{\dfrac{s}{t}\cdot
t}_{=s}\right)  =v_{p}\left(  s\right)  \geq1$. But Proposition 1 **(d)**
(applied to $i=1$ and $n=t$) shows that we have the equivalence $\left(
p^{1}\mid t\right)  \ \Longleftrightarrow\ \left(  v_{p}\left(  t\right)
\geq1\right)  $. Hence, we have $p^{1}\mid t$ (since $v_{p}\left(  t\right)
\geq1$). Thus, $p=p^{1}\mid t$.

Now, $p$ is a common divisor of $s$ and $t$ (since $p\mid s$ and $p\mid t$).
This shows that $s$ and $t$ have a common divisor larger than $1$ (since
$p>1$); but this contradicts the fact that $s$ and $t$ are coprime. This
contradiction shows that our assumption was false. Thus, Proposition 1 **(f)**
is proven. $\blacksquare$

Next, we need a binomial identity:

> **Proposition 2.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then,
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}}=\dfrac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\sum\limits_{k=1}
> ^{n+1}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}.
> \end{align*}

Proposition 2 is the equality (7) in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/481686/
; it is also Exercise 3.20 **(b)** in [my *Notes on the combinatorial
fundamentals of algebra*, version of
2019-01-10](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10).
$\blacksquare$

Next, we need two specific $3$-adic valuations:

> **Lemma 3.** Let $k$ be a positive integer.
>
> **(a)** We have $v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\right)  =-v_{3}\left(
> k\right)  $.
>
> **(b)** If $k$ is odd, then $v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{k}}{k}+\dfrac{2^{2k}}
> {2k}\right)  =-v_{3}\left(  k\right)  $.

*Proof of Lemma 3.* Clearly, $2^{k}$ is an integer; thus, $v_{3}\left(
2^{k}\right)  \in\mathbb{N}$. Similarly, $v_{3}\left(  1+2^{k-1}\right)
\in\mathbb{N}$.

We don't have $3^{1}\mid2^{k}$ (since the only prime divisor of $2^{k}$ is
$2$). Proposition 1 **(d)** (applied to $p=3$, $i=1$ and $n=2^{k}$) yields the
equivalence $\left(  3^{1}\mid2^{k}\right)  \ \Longleftrightarrow\ \left(
v_{3}\left(  2^{k}\right)  \geq1\right)  $. Hence, we don't have $v_{3}\left(
2^{k}\right)  \geq1$ (since we don't have $3^{1}\mid2^{k}$). In other words,
we have $v_{3}\left(  2^{k}\right)  <1$; thus, $v_{3}\left(  2^{k}\right)  =0$
(since $v_{3}\left(  2^{k}\right)  \in\mathbb{N}$).

**(a)** Proposition 1 **(a)** (applied to $p=3$, $a=\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}$ and
$b=k$) yields $v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\cdot k\right)  =v_{3}\left(
\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\right)  +v_{3}\left(  k\right)  $. Comparing this with
$v_{3}\left(  \underbrace{\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\cdot k}_{=2^{k}}\right)
=v_{3}\left(  2^{k}\right)  =0$, we obtain $v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{k}}
{k}\right)  +v_{3}\left(  k\right)  =0$. Hence, $v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{k}}
{k}\right)  =-v_{3}\left(  k\right)  $. This proves Lemma 3 **(a)**.

**(b)** Assume that $k$ is odd. Thus, $k-1$ is even. Now, $2\equiv
-1\operatorname{mod}3$ and thus $2^{k-1}\equiv\left(  -1\right)
^{k-1}=1\operatorname{mod}3$ (since $k-1$ is even). Hence,
$1+\underbrace{2^{k-1}}_{\equiv1\operatorname{mod}3}\equiv1+1=2\not \equiv
0\operatorname{mod}3$, so that $3\nmid1+2^{k-1}$. But Proposition 1 **(d)**
(applied to $p=3$, $i=1$ and $n=1+2^{k-1}$) yields the equivalence $\left(
3^{1}\mid1+2^{k-1}\right)  \ \Longleftrightarrow\ \left(  v_{3}\left(
1+2^{k-1}\right)  \geq1\right)  $. Hence, we don't have $v_{3}\left(
1+2^{k-1}\right)  \geq1$ (since we don't have $3^{1}\mid1+2^{k-1}$ (because
$3^{1}=3\nmid1+2^{k-1}$)). In other words, we have $v_{3}\left(
1+2^{k-1}\right)  <1$; thus, $v_{3}\left(  1+2^{k-1}\right)  =0$ (since
$v_{3}\left(  1+2^{k-1}\right)  \in\mathbb{N}$).

Now, Proposition 1 **(a)** (applied to $p=3$, $a=\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}$ and
$b=1+2^{k-1}$) yields
\begin{align*}
v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\left(  1+2^{k-1}\right)  \right)  =v_{3}\left(
\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\right)  +\underbrace{v_{3}\left(  1+2^{k-1}\right)  }
_{=0}=v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\right)  =-v_{3}\left(  k\right)
\end{align*}
(by Lemma 3 **(a)**). In view of
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\left(  1+2^{k-1}\right)  =\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}+\underbrace{\dfrac
{2^{k}}{k}\cdot2^{k-1}}_{=\dfrac{2^{2k-1}}{k}=\dfrac{2^{2k}}{2k}}=\dfrac
{2^{k}}{k}+\dfrac{2^{2k}}{2k},
\end{align*}
this rewrites as $v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{k}}{k}+\dfrac{2^{2k}}{2k}\right)
=-v_{3}\left(  k\right)  $. This proves Lemma 3 **(b)**. $\blacksquare$

> **Lemma 4.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $m$ be the largest nonnegative
>   integer such that $n\geq3^{m}$. Set
>   \begin{align*}
> a=\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\3^{m}\nmid k}
> }\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\qquad\text{and}\qquad b=\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{
> 1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\3^{m}\mid k}}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}.
> \end{align*}
>   Then:
>
> **(a)** We have $v_{3}\left(  a\right)  >-m$.
>
> **(b)** We have $v_{3}\left(  b\right)  =-m$.

*Proof of Lemma 4.* **(a)** Define a subset $G$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ by
\begin{align*}
G=\left\{  r\in\mathbb{Q}\ \mid\ v_{3}\left(  r\right)  >-m\right\}  .
\end{align*}
Then, $0\in G$ (since $v_{3}\left(  0\right)  =\infty>-m$).

Next, we shall show that the set $G$ is closed under addition. Indeed, let
$s,t\in G$. Then, $s\in G=\left\{  r\in\mathbb{Q}\ \mid\ v_{3}\left(
r\right)  >-m\right\}  $; in other words, $s\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $v_{3}\left(
s\right)  >-m$. Likewise, $t\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $v_{3}\left(  t\right)  >-m$.
Both numbers $v_{3}\left(  s\right)  $ and $v_{3}\left(  t\right)  $ are $>-m$
(since $v_{3}\left(  s\right)  >-m$ and $v_{3}\left(  t\right)  >-m$). Thus,
$\min\left\{  v_{3}\left(  s\right)  ,v_{3}\left(  t\right)  \right\}  >-m$
(since $\min\left\{  v_{3}\left(  s\right)  ,v_{3}\left(  t\right)  \right\}
$ is one of these two numbers $v_{3}\left(  s\right)  $ and $v_{3}\left(
t\right)  $). Now, Proposition 1 **(b)** (applied to $3$, $s$ and $t$ instead
of $p$, $a$ and $b$) yields $v_{3}\left(  s+t\right)  \geq\min\left\{
v_{3}\left(  s\right)  ,v_{3}\left(  t\right)  \right\}  >-m$. In other words,
$s+t\in G$ (by the definition of $G$). Now, forget that we fixed $s,t$. We
thus have proven that $s+t\in G$ for all $s,t\in G$. In other words, the set
$G$ is closed under addition. Hence, $G$ is a submonoid of the additive monoid
$\left(  \mathbb{Q},+\right)  $ (since $0\in G$). Thus, any finite sum of
elements of $G$ is an element of $G$.

Now, let $k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ be such that $3^{m}\nmid k$.
Proposition 1 **(d)** (applied to $3$, $m$ and $k$ instead of $p$, $i$ and
$n$) shows that we have the equivalence $\left(  3^{m}\mid k\right)
\ \Longleftrightarrow\ \left(  v_{3}\left(  k\right)  \geq m\right)  $. Thus,
we do not have $v_{3}\left(  k\right)  \geq m$ (since we do not have
$3^{m}\mid k$ (because $3^{m}\nmid k$)). In other words, we have $v_{3}\left(
k\right)  <m$. But Lemma 3 **(a)** yields $v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{k}}
{k}\right)  =-\underbrace{v_{3}\left(  k\right)  }_{<m}>-m$. In other words,
$\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\in G$ (by the definition of $G$).

Forget that we fixed $k$. We thus have shown that $\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\in G$ for
each $k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ satisfying $3^{m}\nmid k$. In other
words, all addends in the sum $\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots
,n\right\}  ;\\3^{m}\nmid k}}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}$ belong to $G$. Hence,
$\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\3^{m}\nmid k}
}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}$ is a finite sum of elements of $G$, and thus must be an
element of $G$ itself (since any finite sum of elements of $G$ is an element
of $G$). In other words, $\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\3^{m}\nmid k}}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\in G$. Hence, $a=\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in
\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\3^{m}\nmid k}}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\in G$. In
other words, $v_{3}\left(  a\right)  >-m$ (by the definition of $G$). This
proves Lemma 4 **(a)**.

**(b)** We are in one of the following two cases:

*Case 1:* We have $2\cdot3^{m}\leq n$.

*Case 2:* We have $2\cdot3^{m}>n$.

Let us first consider Case 1. In this case, we have $2\cdot3^{m}\leq n$. We
have defined $m$ to be the largest nonnegative integer such that $n\geq3^{m}$.
Thus, $n\geq3^{m}$ but $n<3^{m+1}$. Hence, $3^{m}\leq n$ and $3^{m+1}>n$.
Thus, $3^{m}\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ (since $3^{m}\leq n$) and
$2\cdot3^{m}\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ (since $2\cdot3^{m}\leq n$),
but $3\cdot3^{m}\notin\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ (since $3\cdot
3^{m}=3^{m+1}>n$). Hence, the only multiples of $3^{m}$ that belong to the set
$\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ are $3^{m}$ and $2\cdot3^{m}$. In other
words, the only $k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ that satisfy $3^{m}\mid
k$ are $3^{m}$ and $2\cdot3^{m}$.

But
\begin{align*}
b=\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\3^{m}\mid k}
}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}=\dfrac{2^{3^{m}}}{3^{m}}+\dfrac{2^{2\cdot3^{m}}}{2\cdot
3^{m}}
\end{align*}
(since the only $k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ that satisfy $3^{m}\mid
k$ are $3^{m}$ and $2\cdot3^{m}$). Hence,
\begin{align*}
v_{3}\left(  b\right)  =v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{3^{m}}}{3^{m}}+\dfrac
{2^{2\cdot3^{m}}}{2\cdot3^{m}}\right)  =-v_{3}\left(  3^{m}\right)
\end{align*}
(by Lemma 3 **(b)**, applied to $k=3^{m}$), since $3^{m}$ is odd. Thus,
\begin{align*}
v_{3}\left(  b\right)  =-\underbrace{v_{3}\left(  3^{m}\right)  }_{=m}=-m.
\end{align*}
Hence, Lemma 4 **(b)** is proven in Case 1.

Let us next consider Case 2. In this case, we have $2\cdot3^{m}>n$. Thus,
$3^{m}\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ (since $3^{m}\leq n$), but
$2\cdot3^{m}\notin\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ (since $2\cdot3^{m}>n$).
Hence, the only multiple of $3^{m}$ that belongs to the set $\left\{
1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ is $3^{m}$. In other words, the only $k\in\left\{
1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ that satisfies $3^{m}\mid k$ is $3^{m}$.

But
\begin{align*}
b=\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\3^{m}\mid k}
}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}=\dfrac{2^{3^{m}}}{3^{m}}
\end{align*}
(since the only $k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ that satisfies
$3^{m}\mid k$ is $3^{m}$). Hence,
\begin{align*}
v_{3}\left(  b\right)  =v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{3^{m}}}{3^{m}}\right)
=-v_{3}\left(  3^{m}\right)
\end{align*}
(by Lemma 3 **(a)**, applied to $k=3^{m}$). Thus,
\begin{align*}
v_{3}\left(  b\right)  =-\underbrace{v_{3}\left(  3^{m}\right)  }_{=m}=-m.
\end{align*}
Hence, Lemma 4 **(b)** is proven in Case 2.

We have now proven Lemma 4 **(b)** in both Cases 1 and 2. Hence, Lemma 4
**(b)** always holds. $\blacksquare$

> **Theorem 5.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $m$ be the largest
>   nonnegative integer such that $n\geq3^{m}$. Then,
>   \begin{align*}
> v_{3}\left(  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\right)  =-m.
> \end{align*}

*Proof of Theorem 5.* Define $a$ and $b$ as in Lemma 4. Then, Lemma 4 **(a)**
yields $v_{3}\left(  a\right)  >-m$, but Lemma 4 **(b)** yields $v_{3}\left(
b\right)  =-m$. Thus, $v_{3}\left(  a\right)  >-m=v_{3}\left(  b\right)  $.
Hence, Proposition 1 **(e)** (applied to $p=3$) yields $v_{3}\left(
a+b\right)  =v_{3}\left(  b\right)  =-m$.

But each $k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ satisfies either $3^{m}\nmid k$
or $3^{m}\mid k$ (but not both at the same time). Hence, we can split the sum
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}=\underbrace{\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{
1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\3^{m}\nmid k}}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}}
_{\substack{=a\\\text{(by the definition of }a\text{)}}}+\underbrace{\sum\limits
_{\substack{k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\3^{m}\mid k}}\dfrac{2^{k}
}{k}}_{\substack{=b\\\text{(by the definition of }b\text{)}}}=a+b.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
v_{3}\left(  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\right)  =v_{3}\left(  a+b\right)
=-m.
\end{align*}
This proves Theorem 5. $\blacksquare$

> **Corollary 6.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then:
>
> **(a)** We have
>   \begin{align*}
> v_{3}\left(  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}}\right)  \leq0.
> \end{align*}
>
> **(b)** Assume that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}}=\dfrac{s}{t}$ for
>   two coprime integers $s$ and $t$ satisfying $t\neq0$. Then, $3\nmid s$.

*Proof of Corollary 6.* **(a)** Let $m$ be the largest nonnegative integer
such that $n+1\geq3^{m}$. Then, $n+1\geq3^{m}$ but $n+1<3^{m+1}$.

If we had $3^{m+1}\mid n+1$, then we would have $3^{m+1}\leq n+1$ (since
$3^{m+1}$ and $n+1$ are positive integers), which would contradict
$n+1<3^{m+1}$. Hence, we do not have $3^{m+1}\mid n+1$.

Theorem 1 **(d)** (applied to $3$, $m+1$ and $n+1$ instead of $p$, $i$ and
$n$) yields the equivalence $\left(  3^{m+1}\mid n+1\right)
\ \Longleftrightarrow\ \left(  v_{3}\left(  n+1\right)  \geq m+1\right)  $.
Hence, we do not have $v_{3}\left(  n+1\right)  \geq m+1$ (since we do not
have $3^{m+1}\mid n+1$). In other words, we have $v_{3}\left(  n+1\right)
<m+1$. Thus, $v_{3}\left(  n+1\right)  \leq m$ (since $v_{3}\left(
n+1\right)  $ and $m$ are integers).

Proposition 2 yields
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}}=\dfrac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\sum\limits_{k=1}
^{n+1}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}.
\end{align*}
Multiplying both sides of this equality by $\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}}=\dfrac{2^{n+1}
}{n+1}\cdot\dfrac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}=\sum\limits
_{k=1}^{n+1}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}
}\right)  =v_{3}\left(  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\dfrac{2^{k}}{k}\right)  =-m
\end{align*}
(by Theorem 5, applied to $n+1$ instead of $n$).

But Lemma 3 **(a)** (applied to $k=n+1$) yields
\begin{align*}
v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)  =-\underbrace{v_{3}\left(
n+1\right)  }_{\leq m}\geq-m.
\end{align*}
Now, Proposition 1 **(a)** (applied to $p=3$, $a=\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$ and
$b=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}}$) yields
\begin{align*}
v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}
}\right)    & =\underbrace{v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)  }
_{\geq-m}+v_{3}\left(  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}}\right)  \\
& \geq-m+v_{3}\left(  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}}\right)  .
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
-m+v_{3}\left(  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}}\right)  \leq
v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}
}\right)  =-m.
\end{align*}
Adding $m$ to both sides of this inequality, we find
\begin{align*}
v_{3}\left(  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}}\right)  \leq0.
\end{align*}
This proves Corollary 6 **(a)**.

**(b)** We have $\dfrac{s}{t}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}}$ and thus
$v_{3}\left(  \dfrac{s}{t}\right)  =v_{3}\left(  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac
{1}{\dbinom{n}{k}}\right)  \leq0$ (by Corollary 6 **(a)**). Hence, Proposition
1 **(f)** (applied to $p=3$) yields $3\nmid s$. This proves Corollary 6
**(b)**. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Many thanks for such detailed analysis of this problem.

Comment: Above and beyond the call of duty.